# Child div with negative left margin not allowing parent div to center

Tags: html, css

I have the following div created, but because I'm using negative left margin to offset the icon, I can't center the entire div. We can get away with it on desktop since you can't really tell too easily that the whole div is shifted to the left a bit, but on mobile, the left side of the round icon gets cut off. How can I center the entire div?

[image]

```css
.icon-text-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.icon-box {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 33px;
  margin: 6rem auto;
  padding: 4rem 4rem 4rem 7rem;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 12px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.icon-box p {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.icon-box-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: -90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  height: 177px;
}

.icon-box-icon img {
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid mw-972 icon-text-box">
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="icon-box-icon">
      <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/spotify-logo-png/spotify-simple-green-logo-icon-24.png" />
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `auto` margin you can use a different idea to center and at the same time add some margin on small screen

`margin: 6rem max(90px,(100% - 900px)/2);`

Full code:

```css
.icon-text-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.icon-box {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 33px;
  margin: 6rem max(90px,(100% - 900px)/2);
  padding: 4rem 4rem 4rem 7rem;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 12px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.icon-box p {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.icon-box-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: -90px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  height: 177px;
}

.icon-box-icon img {
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid mw-972 icon-text-box">
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="icon-box-icon">
      <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/spotify-logo-png/spotify-simple-green-logo-icon-24.png" />
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also like below if you want margin on one side:

```css
.icon-text-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.icon-box {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 33px;
  margin: 6rem max(0px,(100% - 900px)/2) 6rem max(90px,(100% - 900px)/2);
  padding: 4rem 4rem 4rem 7rem;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 12px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.icon-box p {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.icon-box-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: -90px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  height: 177px;
}

.icon-box-icon img {
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid mw-972 icon-text-box">
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="icon-box-icon">
      <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/spotify-logo-png/spotify-simple-green-logo-icon-24.png" />
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```